# Don't use migration close votes for review audits

Tags: discussion, review-audits, close-reasons, disputed-review-audits, migration

I ran across a pretty frustrating audit

https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/11653519

The question is about how to remove an expired keychain from a Mac. It's not a programming question. The question is fine... for Super User.

I can only assume it had a close vote originally for migration and people just robo-reviewed it to keep it open (there's no other reason I can see to vote this closed). There's even a comment to that effect. This is deceptive as the question actually does meet the criteria for close/migration. Considering how uncommon those types of closure are this should be a simple change.

Comment: It's never had a close vote on it - it's a fairly heavily upvoted question, with positively scored answers and an accepted answer. That's why choosing to close it is an audit fail. If it's any consolation - you're not the only person it's tripped up when used as a "close" audit... Not much can be done about it I'm afraid, it's just unfortunate it looks like it should be migrated, but wasn't. Hopefully, since it's been used a few times as an audit now, it'll cease being one soon.

Comment: If you believe that it was an off-topic question, why there's no close vote from you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is on-topic, as defined in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), because it is a question about

> - software tools commonly used by programmers

'Positive' audit questions are chosen from questions with a fair amount of upvotes and no downvotes, not just the ones which were once in the queue.

Comment: Really? Are you sure it is "•a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"?

Comment: Is it certificates that are "software tools commonly used by programmers," or Keychain Access? Or...neither.

Comment: Is this really "unique to software development"? I mean, certificates expires everyday, and nothing on the answers tells me that it needs of knowledge only a developer would known of.